# Site em Cakephp não funciona em localhost

Tags: cakephp-2, xampp

Olá.
Tenho um site funcionando em cakephp num servidor na internet.
Estou tentando passar para a minha máquina local (Windows 8.1) onde eu já possuo o xampp funcionando com o CakePHP na versão 2.1.0.
Fiz o Download do site inteiro para a pasta C:\WebServer\xampp\htdocs\RJ\
Fiz backup do banco de dados e fiz o restore no mysql local.
Alterei o arquivo app/config/database.php colocando as configurações do meu banco de dados local.
Ao testar o site está dando erro http 500.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Comment: Opa, se você deletar .htaccess, o que acontece?

Comment: Deletei em httpdocs e em app, mas não fez diferença.
Obrigado por tentar.

Comment: Seu php.ini está com `display_erros=On`? Seu httpd.conf está com `AllowOverride All`? Seu httpd.conf está com `AccessFileName .htaccess`?

Comment: php.ini está com display_errors=On  
O meu httpd.conf está como mostra abaixo  
`<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>`  
Como eu faço para definir o AccessFileName e como deve ser o seu valor?
Obrigado.

Comment: Olá @FelipeDouradinho.
Vc pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: O que você vê em por ultimo (depois de acessar a página) em `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25488/discussion-between-fabricio-wm-and-felipe-douradinho).

Comment: Não encontrei o erro e acabei partindo para uma outra solução.
Obrigado @FelipeDouradinho.

Comment: Imagina...que pena não ter conseguido resolver

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normalizado.Não encontrei o erro e acabei partindo para uma outra solução. Obrigado @FelipeDouradinho